# CID not showing on PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

im attempting to create a link which has categoryName and categoryDescription. Once i click on the link which would take me to the category, the cid on the url does not show up, where it is suppose to have something like cid=1.

here is the code what has been written...

```
<div id="content">

    <?php

        include_once("connection.php");

        //category area
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ecommerce_category_table ORDER BY categoryName ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $categories = "";

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $id = $row['$id'];
                $name = $row['categoryName'];
                $description = $row['categoryDescription'];
                $categories .= "<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."' class='cat_link'>".$name." - ".$description."</a>";
            }

            echo $categories;

        } else {
            echo "<p>There are no categories avaliable yet.</p>";
        }


    ?>

</div><!-- end content -->
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

in your while loop change

```
$id = $row['$id'];
```

to

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this error only.. remove $ sign before 'id' and change this line from

```
  $id = $row['$id'];
```

to

```
  $id = $row['id'];
```